# How to view default zsh settings (HISTSIZE, SAVEHIST, ...)

Tags: environment-variables, default, zsh, built-in

How do I see the current values for all the zsh settings?

e.g., I don't currently have HISTSIZE and SAVEHIST set, so `env | grep HIST` and `set | grep HIST` show nothing.  So then how can I see what default values are being used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no option to get the default value for an undefined variable except parsing documentation or source code.

`HISTSIZE` and `SAVEHIST` are not settings, they are special variables. There is a way to list all variables, but I know of no way to list those that are special and are used as settings.

To help you list parameters implemented as variables, there is the `zsh/parameter` module (`zmodload zsh/parameter` to load it).  It has an associative array `$parameters` where keys are variable names and values are variable type descriptions. Both `HISTSIZE` and `SAVEHIST` appear there as `integer-special`. `HISTCHARS` appears there as `scalar-special`. Note though that `RANDOM` appears here just as `HISTSIZE`: `integer-special`, so you can’t use this to get special variables used as options. But you can always use the `PARAMETERS USED BY THE SHELL` section of `man zshparam`.

I don't know of any option that will allow you to determine default values of those parameters, except parsing documentation or source code.

```
# setopt | grep hist
nobanghist
extendedhistory
histfcntllock
histignorealldups
histignorespace
histnostore
histreduceblanks
histsavenodups
histverify
incappendhistory
```

If you want to see non-default settings:

> If no arguments are supplied, the names of all options currently set are printed.  The form is chosen so as to minimize the differences from the default options for the current emulation  (the  default
>                 emulation  being  native  zsh, shown as  in zshoptions(1)).  Options that are on by default for the emulation are shown with the prefix no only if they are off, while other options are shown without
>                 the prefix no and only if they are on.  In addition to options changed from the default state by the user, any options activated automatically by the shell (for example, SHIN_STDIN or INTERACTIVE) will
>                 be shown in the list.  The format is further modified by the option KSH_OPTION_PRINT, however the rationale for choosing options with or without the no prefix remains the same in this case.

It also makes sense to use:

```
# unsetopt | grep hist
noappendhistory
cshjunkiehistory
histallowclobber
nohistbeep
histexpiredupsfirst
histfindnodups
histignoredups
histlexwords
histnofunctions
nohistsavebycopy
histsubstpattern
sharehistory
```

> If no arguments are supplied, the names of all options currently unset are printed.

Or just follow the help and use

```
# setopt kshoptionprint
# setopt | grep hist
noappendhistory       off
nobanghist            on
cshjunkiehistory      off
extendedhistory       on
histallowclobber      off
nohistbeep            off
histexpiredupsfirst   off
histfcntllock         on
histfindnodups        off
histignorealldups     on
histignoredups        off
histignorespace       on
histlexwords          off
histnofunctions       off
histnostore           on
histreduceblanks      on
nohistsavebycopy      off
histsavenodups        on
histsubstpattern      off
histverify            on
incappendhistory      on
sharehistory          off
```

Note that the output of `setopt` and `unsetopt` match when the `kshoptionprint` option is used.

Comment: Thanks for the try @ZyX, but this only shows boolean settings.  It does not show HISTSIZE and SAVEHIST which are integer settings.

Comment: @RobBednark They are not settings. They are special variables. There is a way to list *all* variables, but I know no way to list only those ones that are special and are used as a settings.

Comment: And some special variables (those that are defined in a C modules) are not fully listable (they appear in `set` output, but with no value).

Comment: @RobBednark One addition though: module `zsh/parameter` (do `zmodload zsh/parameter` to load it) has an associative array `$parameters`. Both `HISTSIZE` and `SAVEHIST` appear there as `integer-special`, another option, `HISTCHARS` appears there as `scalar-special`. Note though that `RANDOM` appears here just as `HISTSIZE`: `integer-special`, so you can’t use this to get special variables used as an options. You can always use “PARAMETERS USED BY THE SHELL” section of `man zshparam` though.

Comment: @RobBednark And there is exactly no option to get the default value for undefined variable except parsing documentation or source code.

Comment: Thanks @ZyX.  Please add your comments to the beginning of your answer, and I'll be happy to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To show the current value, whether you have set it or not (in which case it shows the default value):

```
➜  ~ echo $SAVEHIST
10000
➜  ~ echo $HISTSIZE 
10000
```

Answer (score 0):

i dunno about YOU... (i mean, *[i do use `.prezto`](https://github.com/mralexgray/prezto)*), but this is the "autocompletion" *I get* upon entering `setopt`<kbd>TAB</kbd>...

[image]

which is telling me useful things like..

`-- zsh options (set) --
noaliases      noautoresume      nohashdirs       nohistverify   nonomatch         ...`

and

`-- zsh options (unset) --
allexport              cshjunkiehistory       hashexecutablesonly    kshglob
nullglob               singlecommand ...`